# Can't get rid of white background on RN Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm currently using react-native navigation tab navigators in my app and noticed there's a white background that I can't get rid of when I'm applying a border radius. It's a little difficult to see but i've circled the corners where this is happening.

[image]

Here's a snippet of the `<Tab.Navigator />` props shown below:

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName={SCREENS.DASHBOARD}
  screenOptions={{
  headerShown: false,
  headerShadowVisible: true,
  tabBarShowLabel: false,
  tabBarStyle: {
    height: isPlatformIOS ? 80 : 60,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    paddingTop: isPlatformIOS ? 10 : 5,
    paddingBottom: isPlatformIOS ? 20 : 5,
  },
  tabBarItemStyle: {
    marginBottom: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
  },
  tabBarLabelStyle: {
    fontFamily: FONTS.POPPINS_MEDUIM,
    paddingBottom: isPlatformIOS ? 0 : 5,
  },
  tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.PRIMARY,
}}>
```

There doesn't seem to be a prop that's specifically for styling the tab navigator container but I could be wrong. As a sanity check, I've confirmed that the white corners aren't from the overall containers background color.

Comment: have you tried setting `overflow` to `hidden`? `tabBarStyle = { ..., overflow: 'hidden' }`

Comment: @Harrison yeah I tried it - no luck. It's happening on both iOS and Android. Digging into the interfaces for Tab.Navigator aren't really showing anything available for the container itself.